# Retrieving record through params gets undefine method error for `id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my `ReviewsController`, I have two private methods called in `before_action`:

```
def find_course
  @course = Course.where(:id=>params[:course_id]).first
end

def find_professor
  @professor = Professor.where(:id=>params[:professor_id]).first
end
```

I'm querying `Course` through params, and for some reason, I get  an `undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass` error in my create method:

```
def create
  @review = Review.new(review_params)
  @review.course_id = @course.id
  @review.professor_id = @professor.id
  @review.user_id = current_user.id

  if @review.save
    redirect_to course_path(@course)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The create method is being called in a form partial as such:

```
<%= simple_form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :rating %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form is displayed through a link in the course's show template:

```
<h2><%= @course.name %></h2>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Professors</th>
      <th scope="col">Reviews</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @course.professors.each do |professor| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= professor.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Add Review", new_review_path(course_id: @course.id, professor_id: professor.id) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And `new_review_path` as defined in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :reviews, path_names: { new: 'course/:course_id/professor/:professor_id' }
```

For some odd reason, if I replace `@course = Course.where(:id=>params[:course_id]).first` with `@course = Course.find(7)` (7 being an id of an existing course), the create method works perfectly fine. How do I properly retrieve the Course and Professor records with the given params?

Comment: Check the given answer below and, let me for any further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to "Add Review", new_review_path(course_id: @course.id, professor_id: professor.id) %></td>
```

It will go `reviews/new.html.erb`,

here by you will have to send `course_id` and `professor_id` with hidden field, so that you could fetch `@course` and `@professor` before create action. otherwise `@course` and `@professor` will return `nil`.

> Modified code:-

So far as i understand you don't need to `find_professor` and `find_course` before create action as these two fields are already in `Review` Model, so just pass it with form_for wrapper and pass these all together in strong_params

```
<%= simple_form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :rating %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :course_id, :value => params[:course_id]%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :professor_id, :value => params[:professor_id] %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

in controller

```
def create
  @review = Review.new(review_params)
  if @review.save
    course = @review.course
    #redirect_to course_path(@course)
    redirect_to course_path(course)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating,:comment,:course_id, :professor_id, :user_id)
  end
```

Comment: Hi. I'm still getting these errors: `["Course must exist", "Professor must exist"]`

Comment: @Bargain23 did you change strong params accordingly? as i have a;ready mentioned `professor_id` and `course_id` in `review_params`?

Comment: @Bargain23  what url it creates on clicking `<td><%= link_to "Add Review", new_review_path(course_id: @course.id, professor_id: professor.id) %></td>` this?

Comment: @Bargain23 Are you still stuck in this issue?

Comment: @Bargain23 Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you and for future SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the course and professor objects are fetched and exist before calling the .id

eg:

```
if @course && @professor
  @review = Review.new(review_params)
  @review.course_id = @course.id
  @review.professor_id = @professor.id
  @review.user_id = current_user.id

  if @review.save
    redirect_to course_path(@course)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

It is good habit to use,

```
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
@professor = Professor.find(params[:professor_id])
```

Please go with above, you can get both properly.